# How can I create a list which displays itself when I click it?

Tags: html, list, menu

I am looking to create a menu which will enable me to display a list when I click a link -- I am not sure if I should create a menu title with submenus, or a list with sublists.

For instance,  if I click

"Example 1"

a sub list of Example 1-1, Example 1-2, Example 1-3 etc are displayed.

Any suggestions much appreciated!!!

Comment: So you need like a drop-down menu?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you can use jquery and some styles, there is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/rv87r/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
    <li style="cursor:pointer" onclick="lastElementChild.style.display=(lastElementChild.style.display=='none'?'':'none')">list1
        <ul>
        <li>item1</li>
        <li>item2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>​
```

this is a simple example, you should use jquery or id's to select the inner element because **lastElementChild** will not work on IE<9

if you can't use jquery then you can use

```
(lastElementChild?lastElementchild:lastChild)
```

this will return the last child on IE<9 too

Comment: where do I put the javascript and css elements?  i'm very new to this as you can tell.  thanks so much for your speedy responses, I really appreciate them!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know `CSS` doesn't support clicking. (apart from `a:active`, but it would not help you). It is possible to create a drop-down menu with the `hover` functionality, according to [this](http://csswizardry.com/2011/02/creating-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu/), [this](http://divitodesign.com/css/how-to-dropdown-css-menu/) and [this](http://purecssmenu.com/) tutorials.

To create what you need you will have to use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend a JavaScript based solution, because it's very flexible and easy to achieve. However, if you absolutely want to use HTML/CSS only, you could do it like this:

It works "on click". It's tested in Safari 5/6, Firefox 13 (both OS X) and in IE9 (Windows 7). When you click the container, the list becomes visible. It stays visible until you click outside the open (focused) container (for example the second list) or any other element on the page.

**CSS**

```
div.container > h2 {
    cursor: pointer;
}

div.container > ul {
    display: none;
}

div.container:focus > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container" tabindex="-1">
    <h2>Example 1</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>List Element 1</li>
            <li>List Element 2</li>
            <li>List Element 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/2QdBD/)

Comment: The anonymous don voter strikes again. However. It works and it's a CSS/HTML only solution. I've also added a demo now.

Comment: Got rid of your downvoter :D it works and is a css/html solution as the OP tagged.